# displaying information with values above a set amount

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
 string[,] drinks = {
   {"Coke ","0"},
   {" Diet-Cola ", "0 "},
   {" Fanta ", "0 "},
   {" Dr Pepper ", "0 "},
   {" Orange Juice ", "0 "},
   {" Apple juice ", "0 "},
   {" Grapefruit Juice ", "0 "},
   {" Prune juice ", "0 "}};

string message = "The Drinks you have chosen are: ";

List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>() { 
  txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6, txt7, txt8 };

for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Count; i++)
{
    drinks[i, 1] = textBoxes[i].Text;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (drinks[i,0][1] > 0)
        message = message + drinks[i,0] + drinks[i,1];
}

Data.message = message;
```

It works. the only issue I have is it displays the drinks that have value 0 instead of just displaying the drinks with value above 0.

for example:
Jane does wants to order 3 coke, 2 fanta and a prune juice. And display only these, and not the rest, which would have value 0

Any help to make this happen?

thanks

P.S. my college is using visual studio 2010 express for windows phone

Comment: check the type of the values for drink

Answer (score 0):

The line `if (drinks[i,0][1] > 0)` should be `if (drinks[i,1] > 0)`.

Also, you have `String` value in your array and you are trying to compare it to `Integer` value. So, you should do a type casting:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if ((int)drinks[i,1] > 0)
        message = message + drinks[i,0] + drinks[i,1];
}
```